# Is Onyx Artist 1.2 too weak for Marantz MPM-1000 18mm condenser microphone?

Tags: recording, microphones

When talking I can hear myself normally through the headset but whenever I try to record sound on my laptop (MacBook Pro) I can barely hear anything - the voice is so quiet. How can I fix this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a better fit for sound.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It doesn’t fit well either here or there. It’s a customer support question, best addressed to the manufacturer, as it requires triage. SE is not suited to 20 questions support.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support issue.